# Extracting polygon information from KML file into DataFrame or Shapely using Python

Tags: python, pandas, kml, shapely

I'm trying to get the polygon information from a kml file into a dataframe using python. I've searched a lot on internet but I haven't found it. Also I've tried using shapely to read the polygon points but it didn't work out.  Here it is the polygon kml:

```
<Polygon>
  <tessellate>1</tessellate>
  <outerBoundaryIs>
    <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
            -41.83833790241094,-2.661279139076365,0 -41.90471719429885,-3.031987083995151,0 -41.49083558343574,-3.225825002093066,0 -41.05607562699046,-3.09771956694447,0 -40.41801271168428,-3.119674821078053,0 -36.63002082626241,-5.585744011460483,0 -35.49874571236158,-6.094056115052636,0 -35.11210297540426,-7.280884608267919,0 -34.46680754552457,-7.117718492739846,0 -35.32939749252817,-5.08811180926097,0 -39.94295467544492,-2.782458198144483,0 -41.83833790241094,-2.661279139076365,0 
        </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
```

Is there any library or method to covert the kml file into something we can read and use it?

For example. Can we convert into this:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

poly_kml = Polygon([(-41.83833790241094,-2.661279139076365),(-41.90471719429885,-3.031987083995151),(-41.49083558343574,-3.225825002093066),(-41.05607562699046,-3.09771956694447),(-40.41801271168428,-3.119674821078053),(-36.63002082626241,-5.585744011460483),(-35.49874571236158,-6.094056115052636),(-35.11210297540426,-7.280884608267919),(-34.46680754552457,-7.117718492739846),(-35.32939749252817,-5.08811180926097),(-39.94295467544492,-2.782458198144483),(-41.83833790241094,-2.661279139076365)])
```

Comment: It is off-topic on StackOverflow to seek recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Such a question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) on your own, find a library, and give an earnest attempt at implementation. KMLs are XMLs so can be parsed with well-known Python libraries.

Comment: Maybe try PyKML: https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/